# Is it possible to write hidden information in plain text file?

Tags: text, metadata, plaintext

I have a piece of metadata that I would like to hide in a plain text file, won't be shown by generic text editor, is there a way to do that?

Comment: The only way to do that is to encrypt that data. You can't prevent the text editor from showing all the content of a simple text file.

Answer (score 2):

Not within the file itself. For storing metadata I suggest using alternative data streams in the filesystem. In OS X  (with HFS) they're called Forks and in Windows (with NTFS) they're called Alternate Data Streams. You're probably already familiar with the "Resource fork" on OS X.

...basically it's a hidden file with the same name as the original file (and moves with it), except it's accessed with special (normally illegal) characters in the file path.

Note that ADS files are not moved/copied between incompatible filesystems (e.g. from NTFS to FAT), when compressed into a zip or archived into a tarball, nor when uploaded, so never assume that your ADS file will be persistent (making it useful for storing local-machine-only metadata, such as editor preferences, etc)

- On Windows, you can learn more here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763
- On Mac OS X, you can learn more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSAllocateFork
- On Linux, the main filesystems (extfs: ext3, ext4, etc) do not support forks in the filesystem. When reading a HFS volume on Linux you access forks by appending the fork name to the filename (e.g. "/foo/bar/rsrc" to access the resource fork of the file "/foo/bar").

Comment: OS X forks have been deprecated for some years now.